# Blur a specific portion of a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, gradient

I have a UIImageView and I want to blur only the bottom portion of the image.
Can someone help me with this ?

I have used UIImage + ImageEffects category to blur the image completely. How can I do it for a specific portion only ?

Answer (score 0):

Split your UIImage into two UIImages. Blur the one you want, leave the other one unaffected. The following splits the image exactly at the center, adjust the rects in the CGImageCreateWithImageInRect calls if you want to move the blurred portion.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
CGFloat halfImageHeight = image.size.height / 2.f;
CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, halfImageHeight));
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
CGImageRelease(topImgRef);

CGImageRef bottomImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, halfImageHeight,  image.size.width, halfImageHeight));
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImgRef];
CGImageRelease(bottomImgRef);

// Add blur effects to bottomImage
```